# Custom ordering of pie slices in excel wtih VBA

Tags: excel, pie-chart, vba

Is there a way to customize the order of the slices of a pie chart in excel (2003, 2007, 2010) with VBA so they're not bunched solely by value?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, they are not bunched solely by value but in the order they appear one after the other

Comment: one thing I have found useful when working the charts and series order is that if you can't accomplish it in the chart itself, you can manipulate the data range, so perhaps you could re-order your data range (through VBA) to get the look you are going for.

Comment: Ye, seems obvious enough. I think I was accidentally sorting the data before graphing it...that's why it came out like that.

Comment: yes, it's tricky, maybe 2010 is better, but when trying to get graphs to do certain things in 2007, i found I had to restore to the data range a lot to help me accomplish my tasks. Glad you found your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I don't know why it wasn't working before, but all you do is is reorder the data in the range.

For example to change Item 5 and Item 6's position, simply rearrange.
[image: Slice to change]

like so:
[image]